# Receive TCP Messages without closing the connection

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, tcp

i need some help for my project. I need to receive TCP Messages in nodejs and send them to a web interface via Jquery Ajax.

The Requests are triggerd in the webinterface and send via ajax to the node.js server. This one send a request to tcp server (c++) and pass the answer to the webui.

I made a function for test purporses which includes all necessary tasks.
function tcp_allinone(req,res){

```
    var vRequest = req.body.jsonmsg;
    console.log("< Info > tcp_allinone " + vRequest);

    if (tcpcl == undefined) {
        tcpcl = new net.Socket();
    } 

    tcpcl.connect(objTCPSocket.Port, objTCPSocket.Host, function () {
        tcpcl.write(vRequest);

    });

    tcpcl.on('data', function (data) {
        res.contentType('json');
        res.send({ data: data.toString() });
        tcpcl.end();
    });

    tcpcl.on('error', function (error) {
        res.contentType('json');
        res.send({ data: error.toString() });
        tcpcl.destroy();
    });


    tcpcl.on('close', function () {
        tcpcl.destroy();
        tcpcl = undefined;
    });
```

}

For this project the connection must be hold open and it is not wanted to reopen the connection for each request. In consequence i write to functions, one to start the socket and open the connection, the second to write and receiving messages:

function tcp_starter(req,res){

```
    if (tcpcl == undefined) {
        tcpcl = new net.Socket();
    } 

    tcpcl.connect(objTCPSocket.Port, objTCPSocket.Host, function () {
        console.log("< Info > client_connect ");
        res.contentType('json');
        res.send({ data: "< Info > client_connect" });
    });

    tcpcl.on('error', function (error) {
        res.contentType('json');
        res.send({ data: error.toString() });           
        tcpcl.destroy();
    });

    tcpcl.on('close', function () {
        tcpcl.destroy();
        tcpcl = undefined;
    });

}
```

function tcp_writelisten(req,res){

```
        var vRequest = req.body.jsonmsg;
        console.log("< Info > tcp_writelisten " + vRequest);

        if (tcpcl !== undefined) {
            tcpcl.write(vRequest, function () {
                console.log("< Info > tcp_write: " + vRequest);
            });
        }

        tcpcl.on('data', function (data) {
            res.contentType('json');
            res.send({ data: data.toString() });
            console.log("< Info > tcp_listen: " + data.toString());
        });
```

}

tcp_starter is called at the beginning, tcp_writerlisten each two seconds to get new strings from the server. But with this construct i get the following error message:
ttp.js:707
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
          ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:707:11)

I guess the problem is, that with every function call tcp_writelisten i establish a new Eventlistener and so on i get i++ Receiving messages.

How can i destroy the eventlistener on('data' after receiving without reconnecting? How can i improve this structure?

Big thanks for your help

Comment: When sending data as an http response, you are only allowed to call `res.send()` once because that sends an entire http response.  So, if you try to send another response on the same connection with `res.send()`, you will get the "can't set headers after they are sent" message.  So, if you're trying to send multiple ajax responses on the same ajax connection, you just can't do that - wrong architecture.  You can use `res.write()` to send a partial response each time, but most http clients will wait for the whole response before doing anything.

Comment: In addition, you have to be aware that `tcpcl.on('data', ...)` will not necessarily receive a fully formed chunk of data (it looks like you're expecting a full piece of JSON).  That event just means a packet of data arrived.  It might or might not be a full piece of your data.

Comment: thx for your help @jfriend00 .I understand that i can use res.send only once with the same ajax call. 
Is there a way to close  the event listener .on('data  without disconnecting?

Comment: You can use `.removeListener()` to remove any event listener.

Comment: i tried `tcpcl.removeListener('on', function () { console.log("removeListener"); });` without success. Any Ideas? Thx

Comment: `.removeListener()` only works if you pass it the exact same function reference that was used with `.on()`.  That means you have to define a named function separately, then pass that same function reference to be `.on()` and then later to `.removeListener()`.  To know which listener to remove, the `EventEmitter` goes through its internal list and looks for an exact match of the callback reference.